# rvest not working anymore on a specific website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I need to recover some information about restaurants from tripadvisor. Last year, I was able to use `rvest` without any problems.

Now it seems that this is not working anymore, and I do not understand why.

If I try

```
library(vest)
page <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294197-d17376277-Reviews-HBC_Restaurant-Seoul.html")
```

It does not work (the execution times out), whereas it works on other random websites (wikipedia for example). Tried to set a user agent using `GET` from `httr` but did not solve the problem. I changed my ip with VPN, and did not solve the problem either.
The same happens with `polite` library when using `bow`.

What could be the problem, and what could be the solution (other than Selenium) ?

---

EDIT

I tried with different networks, and try with Tor

```
GET("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294197-d17376277-Reviews-HBC_Restaurant-Seoul.html", 
    use_proxy("socks5://localhost:9050")
    )
```

And it did not work, whereas I was able to verify that the IP actually changed

Comment: I'm able to run your code, It might be an issue with your network. Or maybe the server don't let your PC do the download, because there were too many accesses before (ddos protection).

Comment: ok thanks @danlooo, that is a useful info